# saveEventually and saveInBackground are failing to function after sometime

Tags: android, parse-platform

It seems to work fine but after sometime all calls to saveEventually and saveInBackground are not saving data to parse (there is no callback and there is no error message as well). It seems it is silently discarded. When this happens, we are still able to fetch data from Parse i.e. all read queries work. We are using local storage. The updates start working again once we clear the app data. What could be causing this? How can we debug the requests that are silently discarded?

Comment: parse sdk version we used is 1.10.3

Comment: Have you read the Parse API documentation, about saveInBackgroundWithBlock:? This will return succeeded as true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a synchronous function `saveInBackground`. If you want to have callbacks, you need to call the asynchronous version `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` instead.

Please read the [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects) carefully before posting a question here.

Comment: Sorry. I am using parse sdk in my android app. Not in ios app. saveInBackground() is a asynchronous method only in android. It is working for sometime and started failing.